# I can't set windows controls using IUP with OpenCV's highgui

Tags: c++, opencv, iup, visual-styles

Cheers,
I'm coding a project with Tecgraf's IUP (*iup-3.7_Win32_dll9_lib*) and OpenCV 1.1pre1 on MSVC 2010.

In order to enable window's visual styles, I'm using this manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
<assemblyIdentity
    version="9.0.0.0"
    processorArchitecture="x86"
    name="myapp.exe"
    type="win32"
/>
<description>My App</description>
<dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity 
            type="win32" 
            name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls" 
            version="6.0.0.0" 
            processorArchitecture="x86" 
            publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df" 
            language="*" 
        />
    </dependentAssembly>
</dependency>
<trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <security>
        <requestedPrivileges>
            <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false"/>
        </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
</trustInfo>
</assembly>
```

This is producing a interface like this (which is ok):

[image]

But when I add a module to project which calls **cvLoadImage()** (from highgui), it turns into:

[image]

How can I fix it?

Regards.

Comment: OpenCV 1.1 ? rrrrrllllyyy ? update to 2.4.8, before doing *anything* else

Comment: Anyways, you only really need the `<dependency>` bit, and you also need to call `InitCommonControlsEx` or whatever its name is. Note that `INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX` has nothing to do with reproduction of controls.

Comment: What's wrong with <dependency>? The InitCommonControlsEx has no impact  in this issue.

Comment: OpenCV 2.4.8 is very slow than 1.1, made by intel with ANSI C.

Comment: It is working with new OpenCV. But I think it will run slow :(

Comment: Hi, have you tested if the problem occur by just linking with the module, or by that function call?

Comment: Not related with your problem, but for MSVC 2010 you should use  iup*Win32_dll10_lib*.